# explain the code which is notified as below of ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)

Tags: ios, objective-c

need the explanation of code which is subtracting between height and 568 size of iPhone

```
#define IS_IPHONE5 (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)?NO:YES)
```

Comment: you have used a ternary operator i.e., you have used ? and : to check whether the size of the device is equal to height 568 or not.

Answer (score 0):

That syntax is a ternary conditional, and it looks like this,

```
variable = (something that evaluates to YES or NO)? set variable to this if YES : set variable to this if NO;
```

So, for an iPhone 5 whose screen is 568 tall, the expression evaluates to 0 which is the same as NO, so IS_IPONE5 is set to the value after the colon which is YES. Any other screen size will evaluate to a number other than 0 which is equivalent to YES, so IS_IPHONE5 is set to the value before the colon, NO.

Answer (score 0):

This uses the ternary operator [`?:`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a), that follows this sintax `condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false`.

So...

`([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)` is the condition. In almost every programming language, `0` is evaluated as `false` and anything else is `true`.
In this case, if the height of `mainScreen` is equals to 568 the expression above will result in 0, thats considered false. Picking the second value of the ternary operator, in this case `YES`. Otherwise, it will pick the first value, `NO`.
This tells if the current device is an iPhone 5, that has an screen height of 568pts.